# Ng serve is running but ng test not working

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, jhipster

Initialize created as angular project integrating to jhipster project using angular cli instead of webpack as per the requirement.I replaced angular cli project into jhisper project all the paths in the config is updated.
Ng Serve and ng build is running fine.But Ng test is not running even though in the spec file all the required modules are imported it throws error

**No provider for error**

In the angular project the ng test was working fine.When I checked the developer console(source) of both angular and jhispter project while running ng test.

The jhipster project is not loading the modules in context.html

Any idea?

Note: .

Comment: No provider found seems like a missing dependency in a testing bed? Did you try disabling some tests?

Comment: @MaartenDev I'm tring to run only one spec file other spec are disabled.